# rspec leak from one set to another

Tags: ruby, rspec, rake, rake-task

I have two sets of spec files :
spec/unit1/*_spec.rb
spec/unit2/*_spec.rb

unit2 two has some stubs that is supposed to be used only within unit2 but somehow it affects unit1 tests when I do:

```
RSpec::Core::RakeTask.new(:spec) do |spec|
  spec.fail_on_error = false
  spec.rspec_opts = "--format documentation"
  spec.pattern = FileList['spec/*/*_spec.rb']
end
```

Everything is fine if it is separated like:

```
RSpec::Core::RakeTask.new(:spec1) do |spec1|
  spec.fail_on_error = false
  spec.rspec_opts = "--format documentation"
  spec.pattern = FileList['spec/unit1/*_spec.rb']
end
RSpec::Core::RakeTask.new(:spec2) do |spec2|
  spec.fail_on_error = false
  spec.rspec_opts = "--format documentation"
  spec.pattern = FileList['spec/unit2/*_spec.rb']
end
```

my 
rake spec1
and rake spec2 are fine.

Any idea what the problem is ?
if not how do I write the RakeTask such that
rake spec does rake spec1 + rake spec2

Comment: You're preserving state in your tests. Please post your specs, not just your rake tasks.

Comment: Its lot of files and I dont have states in my specs only the APIs that I call have.

Comment: in any case, can you give me the alternate solution ? how do I write the RakeTask such that rake spec does rake spec1 + rake spec2. Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
task :test_all do
  [ :spec1, :spec2 ].each do |t|
    Rake::Task[t].invoke
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

### Declare Ordered Specs in RSpec

You clearly have state that is persisting between specs. When you run all the tests together, RSpec will run tests in random order unless you specify otherwise with the [`--order` flag](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/command-line/order).

### Declare Ordered Rake Tasks

Alternatively, if you prefer to declare one Rake task to be dependent on another, you can declare that [a Rake task has prerequisites](http://rake.rubyforge.org/doc/rakefile_rdoc.html#label-Tasks+with+Prerequisites). For example:

```
Spec::Core::RakeTask.new(:spec1) do |spec1|
  spec.fail_on_error = false
  spec.rspec_opts = "--format documentation"
  spec.pattern = FileList['spec/unit1/*_spec.rb']
end

RSpec::Core::RakeTask.new(:spec2) do |spec2|
  spec.fail_on_error = false
  spec.rspec_opts = "--format documentation"
  spec.pattern = FileList['spec/unit2/*_spec.rb']
end

desc "run specs in order"
task :ordered_specs => [:spec1, :spec2]
```

Comment: seems ok, but how do i hook 'rake spec' to the tasks spec1 and spec2 ?